# meaning of 'on which'

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I have searched in Google, dictionary and StackExchange and I couldn't understand.
I want to know what is the meaning of 'on which'.

> We call one of those sets the training set, *on which* we learn some properties; we call the other set the testing set, *on which* we test the learned properties.

Comment: You'll need to provide an example showing the context in which you saw this.

Comment: We call one of those sets the training set, on which we learn some properties; we call the other set the testing set, on which we test the learned properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"on which" is an example of a construct where we reverse the order of subject and object around a preposition. The "on" can be any preposition, and "which" simply indicates that the preceding noun is the object of the preposition.

So

> We learn some properties **on** this training set.

becomes

> This is the training set **on which** we learn some properties.

Similarly

> I bought some books at this shop

becomes

> This is the shop at **which** I bought some books

and

> I placed the food in that box

becomes

> That is the box in which I placed the food.